# What is difference between edit performed in query edit vs during modelling?

Tags: powerbi

When I get data into Power BI I can edit the query as well as perform edit to the model.

What is difference between edit performed in query edit vs during modelling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edit the query, you use Power Query, with its own Query Editor user interface. The steps you apply are recorded in the "M" language. Use Power Query to extract, transform, and finally load data into the Data Model.

Once the data is in the Data Model, you use DAX to create measures that you use in visuals. You can also use DAX to add more columns or even tables to the data model.

Whether to use Power Query or DAX to add columns or tables to the data model depends on a variety of factors. Some things are dead easy to do in Power Query, but harder to achieve with DAX, and vice versa. If you create a column with a formula that depends on a DAX measure, then you can only do that with DAX, because Power Query is not aware of the measures that are created after the load into the data model.

Power Query is very powerful, but the M code syntax is very different to the Excel formula syntax, or the VBA macro language. Learning to write advanced M code can be quite challenging.

DAX, on the other hand, behaves very similar to Excel formulas. Many Excel functions can even be used in DAX verbatim. If you know Excel, you've already got a head start on DAX and you can ease your way into it by learning additional functions and then expanding into more complex formulas.

The latter is probably the reason why many data manipulations are done in DAX, even though they could as well have been done in Power Query.

There are also some efficiencies with data storage and performance. Power Query makes use of query folding with SQL queries, for example, where its transformations are actually performed at the data source, i.e. on the SQL server side, and not in desktop client, and only the final query result is transferred to the desktop client.

**Edit after comment:** When the data is loaded into the data model, an algorithm processes the data and sorts it in a way that is most efficient for maximum compression and minimum storage. I don't have any concreate examples, but adding a column in Power Query will result in a smaller footprint than adding the same column with DAX. Read more about the compression algorithm VertiPaq here: https://towardsdatascience.com/inside-vertipaq-in-power-bi-compress-for-success-68b888d9d463

But apart from that, it mainly comes down to personal preference based on skill and experience.

By the way, many of your questions can be answered by reading through the Microsoft documentation, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/import-modeling-data-reduction

Comment: Please can you mention about storage and memory usage. Edits (example adding a column) performed at query editor level and data modelling level are both stored in storage or is the later calculated on the fly (like when we use measures).

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the tour. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up